# Multiple xsl templates in one xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xslt that is currently removing all namespaces from my incoming xml.  What I would like to do is create a new xml document using the xpath from the modified version.

Here is my current xsl file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want it to do something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Start of next template that uses above modification -->

    <xsl:template>
        <newParent>
            <newChild>
                <xsl:value-of select="xpath to data from modified template"/>
            </newChild>
        </newParent>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: Show expected output and a sample input. Your question is confusing at best and no one can guess at what you want.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you want to do a two-pass transformation. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772482/two-phase-transformation-using-xslt-2-0 or search for "XSLT two-pass transformation".